# Stata Robust F test with general restrictions

Tags: stata

In Stata does running the following code give you a robust F statistic for the test constant=0 and slope=1?

```
regress cD DEFF, robust 
test _cons=0  
test DEFF=1, accumulate
```

Why can you not test these in one line of code like you can with exclusion restrictions?

Comment: This question has been well answered, but it's hard to see it as a programming problem in any strict sense. Statalist would be a better fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
test (_cons=0) (DEFF=1)
```